# How to modify the tweet.created_at.date() within a for loop using Tweepy

Tags: python, for-loop, datetime, tweepy, timedelta

I currently have a for loop which appends tweets to a list if they were created before 9:30am on a weekday, excluding holidays. I want to append a maximum of 100 tweets per day, and once those 100 tweets have been reached, I want to move on to the next day.
My for loop correctly recognizes when 100 tweets have been appended, and correctly switches to the next day once, but it is not updating the tweet.created_at.date() to the new day, so the correct tweets are not being appended after the first 100.
Any help at all would be amazing

```
day = datetime.now()
tweets_per_day = 0
# Iterate through the pages of results
all_tweets = []
for tweet in cursor.items(limit=500):
    current_day = day
    tweet_date = pd.to_datetime(tweet.created_at.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    # Only add tweets which were made before market open on a weekends
    if tweet.created_at.time() < time(hour=9, minute=30) and current_day.weekday() < 5:
        # Do not add tweets if they were made on a holiday
        if not holiday_df['Date'].eq(tweet_date).any():
            tweets_per_day += 1
            if tweets_per_day <= 100:
                print(tweet.created_at.date())
                print(tweet.created_at.time())
                print(tweets_per_day)
                all_tweets.append(tweet.text)
            else:
                # Go page by page for efficiency
                for page in cursor.pages():
                    # Get the first tweet in the page
                    tweet = page[0]
                    if tweet.created_at.date() < current_day.date():
                        print(tweet.created_at.date())
                        all_tweets.append(tweet)  # This code is working, I do want to append the tweet
                        tweets_per_day = 0  # This code is working, I want to restart the tweets_per_day count
                        day -= timedelta(days=1)  # This code does not alter the day
                        break
                    # If the tweet's created_at date is the current day, continue the loop
                    else:
                        continue
```

After correctly switching to the right date, I tried to store the tweet.created_at.date() in a current_day variable, and update that variable using -= datetime.timedelta(days=1), to shift the date backwards by 1. But this didnt work.

Comment: After subtracting a day the result is not used anywhere but "current_day" is overwritten in the next iteration of the outer for-loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I created a day variable using datetime.now() and changed current_day to be equal to day. Then to swtich the current_day I included the line day -= timedelta(days=1). However the code is still not correctly switching the days

Comment: Now the code also does not correctly recognize the time, and is appending tweets created after 9:30

Comment: After subtracting a day from "day", how is "day" used then to influence "current_day"? Better show the modified code in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher just updated the code in the post, thanks!

Comment: The time in "current_day" is now no longer related to the time of the tweet, so you shouldn't check if "current_day" is before 9:30 but check the time of the tweet as you did it similarly with the date in "tweet_date".

Comment: What exactly means "the code is still not correctly switching the days"?

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks so much, just noticed that. I updated the code again but it's still not quite there yet. It correctly gets the first 100 tweets from the right day, and updates the date, but now it continuously goes into the else block and skips the initial "if tweets_per_day <= 100 and tweet.created_at.date() == current_day.date():" block that I want it to go into. By not correctly switching the days, I just mean that ideally I want the code to be able to switch the date of the tweets that are appended after 100 tweets. i.e. 100 tweets day 1 -> switch to day 2 -> 100 tweets day 2, etc.

Comment: I don't see anything specific so I can only recommend to add more "print"s to see what happens. Additionally I think that using the cursor in two loops is not a good idea. Additionally in the inner loop the cursor returns pages but only the first entry of a page is stored while others are thrown away.